# How do you load GFYCAT gifs?

Tags: android

imgur gifs load fine, but I can't get GFYCAT one's to load with glide

```
Glide.with(mContext).asGif().load("https://i.imgur.com/94Ui2gf.gif").into(imageView);
```

however this gfycat one doesn't

```
Glide.with(mContext).asGif()
.load("https://gfycat.com/peskyadventurousleveret-star-wars-the-last-jedi-crying-feels.gif")
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: The link you provided is a Video, not GIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the actual GIF url. You can find it by going to GIF on gfycat and then running this code:

```
window.location = document.querySelector("meta[property='og:image']").content;
```

The location of the GIF in your question is `https://thumbs.gfycat.com/PeskyAdventurousLeveret-size_restricted.gif`

If you know the slug of the GIF, you can use this format:

> https://thumbs.gfycat.com/**CamelCaseSlug**-size_restricted.gif

Note that the slug must be properly capitalized here, whereas it does not on regular gfycat pages.

Comment: wait how would I make that implementation on android? Do I need to make a post request with the current URL?

Comment: You didn't have anything in your question about performing GIF lookups via android, the only context you gave was loading a hardcoded URL. If you know the slug of the GIF, you can use this format: `https://thumbs.gfycat.com/CamelCaseSlug-size_restricted.gif`

Comment: How would I dynamically set them to uppercase though... gifs like this with more than 3 words https://gfycat.com/agitatedunconsciousbrahmanbull-slippery-driveway-travel-events I wouldn't know which to capitalize

Comment: Yeah if you don't know the actual slug then there's not a clean solution. You could pre-fetch the page and parse it for the <meta property="og:image"> tag, and pull the content attribute out of it. That value is the full size GIF url.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is a Video, not GIF, so you can download it as an MP4 file as following :

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    String savedMP4FilePath = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urlParams) {
        int count;
        String videoName = urlParams[1] + ".mp4";
        File storageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                        + "/GYFCAT/");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            success = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            File videofile = new File(storageDir, videoName);
            savedMP4FilePath = videofile.getAbsolutePath();
            if (!videofile.exists()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlParams[0]);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();
                    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(videofile);
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
        return savedMP4FilePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

    }
  }
```

and call it :

```
new DownloadFile().execute("https://giant.gfycat.com/PeskyAdventurousLeveret.mp4", "GFYCAT_GIF");
```

When the MP4 file downloaded you can play it with `VideoView`

OR

you can use this library [MagicalExoPlayer](https://github.com/HamidrezaAmz/MagicalExoPlayer) (I haven't tried it yet)

```
 AndExoPlayerView andExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.andExoPlayerView);
 andExoPlayerView.setSource("https://giant.gfycat.com/PeskyAdventurousLeveret.mp4");
```

Comment: How is it a mp4? it says .gif I also don't want to download the entire mp4

Comment: @davids. unfortunately, it's a video, you can check it out by right-clicking on it, a popup menu will appear with all options like ( save video as & Copy the video address)

Comment: How do I get the video URL then from Android?

Comment: @davids. please check this link [gfycat-android-sdk](https://github.com/gfycat/gfycat-android-sdk)